# Why are characteristic X-rays produced in greater numbers than bremsstrahlung rays?

Tags: photons, radiation, x-rays

In a typical X-ray spectrum we can observe that characteristic X-rays occur in noticeably larger numbers compared to other energies.

[image]

Characteristic emission is a separate phenomenon from bremsstrahlung. Characteristic emission is unique to a distinct set of energies, but bremsstrahlung can produce X-rays of any energy, including the characteristic energy. So the effect of characteristic emission is "stacked" on top of the bremsstrahlung effect, and this is why we can observe spikes on the spectrum. Does this make sense?

Comment: You've answered your question: "the effect of characteristic emission is "stacked" on top of the bremsstrahlung effect, and this is why we can observe spikes on the spectrum. "

Comment: what are the units of intensity? Is it energy per unit energy or is it X-rays per unit energy. The latter carries a 1/E factor in the spectrum, and the Brem cross section (photons/energy) is IR divergent, so infinity brems is more than the number of characteristic X-rays.

Comment: Photon intensity is a poor choice here. Energy fluence would be better or even photon count.